# Android Project Folders and "styles.xml"

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-theme

Why does my Android Project (created with Eclipse) have three `styles.xml` files?  These files are located in the following folders:

- values
- values-v11
- values-v14

What is the difference between each of these files?  Why are there three values folders?

The only thing in each of these `styles.xml` files is an AppTheme property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are values for the different API Levels. The folder values is the default folder for (in this case) API Level 11<, the folder values-v11 is for the API Level >=11, values-v14 for API Level >=14. You need these because sometimes you need different values for some API Levels.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

Those folders make it so that each API level uses a difference style/theme, the default android skeleton project has them to ensure Holo gets used on API levels that support it, instead of the OEM skin.